# Multiple boxplots from multi-index data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in a multi-index DataFrame structured as follows:

```
                    0      1
method metric
HASH   L2_TCM     287    296
       TOT_CYC   6211   6100
RECV   L2_TCM     331    323
       TOT_CYC  10881   7524
SYNTH  L2_TCM     869    856
       TOT_CYC  29117  29560
```

The columns 0 and 1 indicate the samples for each method-metric pair. I have shown 2 samples for illustrative purposes, but there may be more than 2.

Ideally, I'd like use pandas to create a set of figures, one for each method that contains a boxplot for each metrics using the samples. This sounds like it should be straightforward, but I am struggling to get the groupings to work correctly.

Any suggestions on how to plot this or reconfigure the DataFrame to simplify the plotting would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I've tried using `df.boxplot(by='method')` as a starting point, but that fails with a `KeyError`. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603823/boxplot-with-multiindex?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question, I noticed that `.boxplot` seems to expect columns of data rather than rows. I have similarly tried to use `df.T.boxplot(by='method')` but to no avail.

Edit: Added what I've tried so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

'''
method metric       0      1
HASH   L2_TCM     287    296
HASH   TOT_CYC   6211   6100
RECV   L2_TCM     331    323
RECV   TOT_CYC  10881   7524
SYNTH  L2_TCM     869    856
SYNTH  TOT_CYC  29117  29560
'''

df = pd.read_clipboard()

# this is what your data looks like...
df.groupby([
    'method',
    'metric'
]).agg({
    '0' : 'max',
    '1' : 'max'
})

# I reshaped it to have no multiindex...


# And then melt the data to work with seaborn
df1 = df.melt(id_vars = [
    'method',
    'metric'
])

sns.boxplot(data = df1, x = 'method', y = 'value', hue = 'metric');
```

[image: final]

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you! It seems that having the multi-index was making this more complicated than it needed to be.